# Flow disjoint union checks work for literal strings but not constants

Tags: flowtype

I'm trying to properly type redux actions with Flow but it's not typechecking disjoint types correctly when using constants for the action types.

I've read in many places that this is the right way to do it but I can't get the `DOUBLE` constant to error out (so this is not really typing the switch statement properly).

Is there another way to do this?

```
// @flow
export const INCREMENT: 'INCREMENT' = 'INCREMENT';
export type IncrementAction = {|
    type: typeof INCREMENT,
|};

export const DECREMENT: 'DECREMENT' = 'DECREMENT';
export type DecrementAction = {|
    type: typeof DECREMENT,
|};

export const DOUBLE: 'DOUBLE' = 'DOUBLE';
export type DoubleAction = {|
    type: typeof DOUBLE,
|};

// Notice I didn't include DoubleAction
export type Action = IncrementAction | DecrementAction;

type State = {|
    counter: number,
|};

export const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INCREMENT:
            return { counter: state.counter + 1 };
        case DECREMENT:
            return { counter: state.counter - 1 };
        // This case should fail because it's in none of the actions in the disjoint union
        case DOUBLE:
            return { counter: state.counter * 2 };
        // This case does fail because it's a literal instead of a constants
        case 'TRIPLE':
            return { counter: state.counter * 3 };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: It's actually a known issue: [facebook/flow#5083](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5083). Using literals or `if` instead of `switch` both works.